# I expect these 2 sql statements to return same number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my mind these 2 sql statements are equivalent.

My understanding is:

the first one i am pulling all rows from tmpPerson and filtering where they do not have an equivalent person id. This query returns 211 records.

The second one says give me all tmpPersons whose id isnt in person. this returns null.

Obviously they are not equivalent or theyd have the same results. so what am i missing? thanks

```
select p.id, bp.id
From person p
right join(
    select distinct id
    from tmpPerson
) bp
on p.id= bp.id
where p.id is null

select id
from tmpPerson
where id not in (select id from person)
```

I pulled some ids from the first result set and found no matching records for them in Person so im guessing the first one is accurate but im still surprised they're different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I much prefer `left join`s to `right join`s, so let's write the first query as:

```
select p.id, bp.id
From (select distinct id
      from tmpPerson
     ) bp left join
     person p
     on p.id = bp.id
where p.id is null;
```

(The preference is because the result set keeps all the rows in the *first* table rather than the *last* table.  When reading the `from` clause, I immediately know what the first table is.)

The second is:

```
select id
from tmpPerson
where id not in (select id from person);
```

These are not equivalent for two reasons.  The most likely reason in your case is that you have duplicate ids in `tmpPerson`.  The first version removes the duplicates.  The second doesn't.  This is easily fixed by putting `distinct`s in the right place.

The more subtle reason has to do with the semantics of `not in`.  If *any* `person.id` has a `NULL` value, then all rows will be filtered out.  I don't think that is the case with your query, but it is a difference.

I strongly recommend using `not exists` instead of `not in` for the reason just described:

```
select tp.id
from tmpPerson tp
where not exists (select 1 from person p where p.id = tp.id);
```

Comment: it was the second. changing the query to 

`select id
from tmpPerson
where id not in (select ISNULL(id, 0) from person)` fixed it. thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

```
select id
from tmpPerson
where id not in (select id from person)
```

If there is a null id in tmp person then they will not be captured in this query. But in your first query they will be captured. So using an isnull will be resolve the issue

```
where isnull(id, 'N') not in (select id from person)
```